# EXCEL - Find category by searching keyword from other worksheet

Tags: excel, search, match, categories

I want to get sales by category (states).

In *Sheet1*, there're state's names in row A (A1 to A6) and cities in the column.
Each cities belongs to states,

e.g.
Sydney belongs to NSW, and Melbourne & Geelong belong to VIC.

[image]

Then *Sheet2* contains sales data like shown below.
I want to calculate sales by state each month.
At the moment, each cells between row D and row I has a formula like below;

(e.g. F5)

=IF(AND(ISERR(SEARCH("Brisbane",B5)),ISERR(SEARCH("Gold  Coast",B5)),ISERR(SEARCH("Cairns",B5))),"",C5)

[image]

But I'm sure there would be better and more simple nifty way to do this. As shops increase, this current formula gets more complicated. So it's needed to be optimized.

I would like to make these calculation simple using vlookup or something.. but no luck so far.
Any advice, detailed if possible, would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked into using pivot tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an array formula. For example, in `D3` use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*"&Sheet1!$B$1:$D$6&"*",$B3))+(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$6=""),0,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$6))))=D$1,$C3,""),"Not found")
```

(To enter an array formula, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

- The `SEARCH` looks at the store name in `B3` and compares it to all names in `Sheet1!B1:D6` with a `*` wildcard before and after. This won't be an error if it matches.
- Adding the `+(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$6="")` gives an OR the cell is blank (otherwise `**` would match).
- If it isn't an error, we'll get the `ROW` of the corresponding match and we take the highest (`MAX`) row match.
- We then use `INDIRECT` to get the cell value in column A of Sheet1 (the State code) and compare that to the state in the top row of our column
- This is wrapped in an `IFERROR` to tell us if our store doesn't match any city

Array formulas are a great tool, but a little confusing! Rather than work on a single cell, array formulas work on each cell of an array. Typically this is for counts, sums, averages, etc. By including “logic maths”, you can do some really strange things in a single formula. A good resource is [link]http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx  Always remember to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or really strange things will happen!