# finding dynamically a match between two tables; one has text and the other the search pattern

Tags: excel, search, design-patterns, excel-formula, vlookup

## EXCEL - finding a match between two tables

[https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2WLaA0HlUBVWnlwaFRGMmdwaVU&usp=sharing  - excel file](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2WLaA0HlUBVWnlwaFRGMmdwaVU&usp=sharing)
FILE : vraag.xlsm

I would like to make a dynamically solution, for searching a text pattern from one table if it is also in the text of an other table (in different columns).
(Dynamically, I mean if the are elements are added, deleted, changed)

So searching if one the elements from *column 'ID_type'* can be found in the text of *column 'element'* 
!

- table A  [*T_example*] : in a column contains tekst (within maybe one
  of the elements of the other table)
- table B  [*T_rec_by_type*] : contains several possible strings

[image]

[image]

**edited : next seems to be a wrong approach** : `MATCH()`

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A23;T_rec_by_type[ID_type];1;FALSE));FALSE; "File found in row "   & MATCH(A23;T_rec_by_type[ID_type];0))
```

[image]

In the first example (exactly match, so not as search pattern), it works.
But the idea is to search in the text to find the searchpattern ... and return via VLOOKUP a value from an other column (in this stadium just *ID_type*).

---

### A possible solution found in an answer online

[EXCEL - Find category by searching keyword from other worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310687/excel-find-category-by-searching-keyword-from-other-worksheet)

[https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2WLaA0HlUBVWnlwaFRGMmdwaVU&usp=sharing  - excel file](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2WLaA0HlUBVWnlwaFRGMmdwaVU&usp=sharing)
FILE : SearchAMatchtingStad.xlsm

[image: SearchAMatchingStad]

In the hope to find a solution ... for my case via this answer, I tried it out but unfortunately without succes.
So what am I doing wrong?
(I tried it first with tables, columns and ...

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(CONCATENATE("*";Table1[[stad 1]:[stad 3]];"*");[@shop]))+(Table1[[stad 1]:[stad 3]]="");0;ROW(Table1[[stad 1]:[stad 3]]))))=Table2[[#Headers];[antwerpen]];[@sales];"");"Not found")
```

to figure out my fault/problem, why it doesn't work ... 
I did it just by one cell, but without luck)

```
 =  IFERROR( IF( INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & MAX( IF( ISERROR( SEARCH("*"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4&"*";$B8)) + (Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4="") ; 0 ; ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4)))) = D$7;$C8; "") ; "Not found")
```

A small remark [ENTERING AN ARRAY FORMULA: press the CTRL SHIFT and ENTER](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx)

---

### In a way it seems that there is an issue with array formulas

So when I do a one to one 'search' it seems to work  `=SEARCH("*"&B2&"*";$B8)`
But when I do it with an array (despite it is still an array but with "\" instead of **{ "genk" ; "mol" ; "leuven" ; ... }**), it seems to be a problem, or not working the way I wished. `=SEARCH(CONCATENATE("*";OR(Table1[[stad 1]:[stad 3]]);"*");B8)`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I give it a last try.

But with `OR` or without gives the same result.
And to check if it maybe a problem is with `CONCATENATE`, I created a simular table with the wildcard already implemented.

**Maybe ONE important thing, I forget to say there is always a space in front of the ID_TYPE.
And the ID_TYPE itself followed by a number (of maximum 3 characters) and a space.**

[image]

You may have to change `;` to `,` and `,` to `.` according to your local.

---

---

@Tom Sharpe

Thanks for your answer, but when I tried it out, it doesn't work.
Maybe ONE important thing, I forget to say there is always a space in front of the ID_TYPE.
And the ID_TYPE itself followed by a number (of maximum 3 characters) and a space.

I used 0 - in case default, not found.

Correct Tom, if I use  '=FORMULATEXT(B35)', I see the formula is surrouded by { and }.
So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
And it worked fine at your place, you did it with my spreadsheet? Strange.

I uploaded the file changed as "vraag2.xlsm"

---

---

@user3616725

Maybe ONE important thing, I forget to say there is always a space in front of the ID_TYPE.
And the ID_TYPE itself followed by a number (of maximum 3 characters) and a space.

put new file in the shared folder : vraag2.xlsm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution without using Regex. It tests each element in the first column of the table in A1:A7 (ID_type) using FIND to see if it is a substring of the element in A25 and below. The row numbers of any matching cells in a1:a7 are stored in an array. Because you want the first match, it uses MIN to find the lowest row number. If there is no match, it stores a reference to a cell which is outside the table, i.e. A8. I'm using FIND because I don't want to match lowercase, otherwise ... "3 spots plafond" would match with A because it has an 'a' in it.

If you enter the array formula in (say) d25 and pull it down, it will give the row number of the first matching cell in the table. If you enter the second formula in (say) e25 and pull it down, it will give the corresponding cell in another column of the table, in this case column B (type).

The first formula in structured form is:-

=MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND(T_rec_by_type[[#Data],[ID_type]],A25)),ROW(A$8),ROW(T_rec_by_type[[#Data],[ID_type]])))

and the second one in structured form is

=IFERROR(INDEX(T_rec_by_type[[#All],[type]],D25),"Not found")

The formulae in ordinary notation (which I find a bit easier) are

=MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND(A$2:A$7,A25)),ROW(A$8),ROW(A$2:A$7)))

and

=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$7,D25),"Not found")

ROW(A$8) above is just a not very subtle way of getting a row number which is greater than that of any rows in the table. You could just use an arbitrary large number, or perhaps add a Totals row to the first table and use that to get the reference.

I haven't been able to work out why your vlookup didn't work with the table (it's OK if I copy the cells somewhere else), perhaps other people can comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work
(see screenshot in my question)

Maybe ONE important thing I forget to say there is always a space in front of the ID_TYPE.

Comment: I did test it on your spreadsheet and it was OK. Did you definitely put the first formula in as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter? On the screenshot, it should appear with curly brackets round it

Comment: Correct Tom, if I use  '=FORMULATEXT(B35)', I see the formula is surrouded by { and }.
So I don't understand why I do wrong.
And it worked fine if you did it with my spreadsheet? Strange.

I uploaded the file changed as "vraag2"

Comment: Try =MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND(T_rec_by_type[[#Data],[ID_type]],Table12[[#This Row],[Column1]])),ROW(A$8),ROW(T_rec_by_type[[#Data],[ID_type]])))    ...the ROW(a$8) is really important otherwise MIN will always give zero and you have to consistently use either #Data or #All.

Comment: --I haven't been able to work out why your vlookup didn't work with the table (it's OK if I copy the cells somewhere else), perhaps other people can comment.-- by Tom.

Of course Tom, thanks onbeforehand ... and your last tip was

Comment: Tom, I've a question about the formula; it was not working with the `0` or the number < the last row of the table `ROW()`. Do you know why? Because here we already working `IF` ... part.

Comment: Kris it was because we were using the MIN function to find the lowest matching row number. Say it found a match in rows 2 & 3 and gave zero for all other rows - then the MIN function would just give min(0,2,3...) = zero. So to avoid this we need to generate a large number if there's no match e.g.  =min(8,2,3...)=2.

Answer (score 1):

using REGEX functions from MORFUNC ADDON*

I used your vraag.xlsm shhet that you linked to.

In cell `C25` put: `=REGEX.MID(TABLE12[[#ThisRow],[element]],MCONCAT(T_rec_by_type[ID_type],"|"),,TRUE)`

this will give you the first (left-most) of the "keywords" that appears in the corresponding "element" cell.

This is almost there. but you say that the "SSR" sensor is more important than V, so that's the one that should be displayed if they both appear.

this is not pretty, but will work (if u provide more details on possible "ID_type"s and the order of things in "element" field i might be able to come up with something more elegant...) :
paste in cell `D25`:

`=IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$2,TRUE),A$2,IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$3,TRUE),A$3,IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$4,TRUE),A$4,IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$5,TRUE),A$5,IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$6,TRUE),A$6,IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[element]],A$7,TRUE),A$7,""))))))`

copy `C25` and `D25` down, for the other elements

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Comment: If I use an other column with numerics 
ie by the function ROW() and in the formula use an offset MIN(PRIO)-1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Maybe ONE important thing, I forget to say there is always a space in front of the ID_TYPE.
And the ID_TYPE itself followed by a number (of maximum 3 characters) and a space.


About your question : "if u provide more details on possible "ID_type"s and the order of things in "element" field i might be able to come up with something more elegant.." ... 
No, that is not possible because if it is dynamically, so that's why I suggested an extra column "prio"... (see screen shot in my question)

Comment: the following formula will return the correct sensor - no need for the PRIO. (notice the array formula. this has to be confirmed with ctr-shift-enter)  ___ FORMULA FOR `D25`: `{=WMID(MCONCAT(IF(REGEX.COMP(Table12[[#This Row],[Column1]],T_rec_by_type[ID_type]),T_rec_by_type[ID_type],""),";"),,1,";")}`

Comment: user3616725, thank you very much ... despite of your effort and your answer is greatfull, and it works fine.
I'm just allowed to choice one answer.